# Unable to start and stop redis server

Tags: redis

I used the following commands to install redid from source:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
 sudo apt-get install tcl8.5
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
make test
sudo make install
cd utils
sudo ./install_server.sh
```

The install_server.sh shell script installs redis as a background daemon

These were the configuration options:

```
Selected config:
Port           : 6379
Config file    : /etc/redis/6379.conf
Log file       : /var/log/redis_6379.log
Data dir       : /var/lib/redis/6379
Executable     : /usr/local/bin/redis-server
Cli Executable : /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
```

While the redid-server executable is in the $PATH, I cannot restart the server:

```
/etc/init.d/redis-server restart
9908:C 12 Oct 15:52:17.192 # Fatal error, can't open config file '/etc/init.d/redis-server'
```

I want to be able to control it like a system service.